# Метод decode не преобразовывает некоторые символы в строку

Tags: python, python-3.x, кодировка, utf-8

У меня есть массив с индексами символов из таблицы utf-8:

```
[190, 123, 201, 72, 52, 166, 102, 60].
```

При использовании функции `bytes` тоже все нормально отображается:

```
b'\xbe{\xc9H4\xa6f<'
```

Но при попытке использовать метод decode возникает ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
a = [190, 123, 201, 72, 52, 166, 102, 60] # индексы символов из таблицы(utf-8)
b = bytes(a)                              # b'\xbe{\xc9H4\xa6f<'
c = b.decode('utf-8')                     # тут происходит ошибка
```

Если в decode добавить параметр "ignore" я получаю только [123, 72, 52, 102, 32, 60], но мне необходимы и оставшиеся символы.

Из-за чего это может происходить ?

P.S Откуда взялись эти числа

Ситуация следующая: У меня есть текст, который я перевёл в формат list("some_text".encode("utf-8")). После этого у меня выполняется des шифрование, и в результате я получаю список "символов указанный выше".

Comment: Это вообще скорее всего какие-то бинарные данные, а не текст в какой-то кодировке.

Comment: А что должно получиться то хоть на выходе, хоть примерно?

Comment: А то может это вообще `UTF-16` и иероглифы на выходе будут ))

Comment: Это точно utf-8, ситуация следующая: У меня есть текст, который я перевёл в формат list("some_text".encode("utf-8")). После этого у меня выполняется des шифрование, и в результате я получаю список "символов указанный выше".

Comment: @murlock А что у `des` шифрования на выходе, почему вы думаете, что это должны быть какие-то читаемые символы вообще?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> После этого у меня выполняется des шифрование, и в результате я
> получаю список "символов указанный выше".

На выходе шифрования `DES` вы получаете массив байт, которому не соответствуют никакие символы, это просто байты. Есть стандарты шифрования, которые получают на вход текст и выдают на выход тоже текст (обычно это старые, "человеческие" шифры, которые делались вручную по таблицам), но `DES` это не такой стандарт, он получает на вход байты и на выходе у него тоже байты. Да, ему можно подать на вход байты, соответствующие некоему тексту в некоей кодировке, но на выходе после шифрования у него будут просто байты, уже не соответствующие никакой кодировке. Их можно представить, например, в виде шестнадцатеричного текстового представления этих байтов, но это и всё, никакому тексту в определённой кодировке из эти байты не соответствуют.

Answer (score 5):

```
a = [190, 123, 201, 72, 52, 166, 102, 60]
b = bytes(a)

c = b.decode('Windows-1251')
```

```
>>> c
'ѕ{ЙH4¦f<'
```

Answer (score 3):

А вы уверены, что на входе валидный `utf-8`? Например, ваши байты без проблем декодируются в кодировке `latin1`.

```
>>> c = b.decode('latin1')
>>> print(c)
¾{ÉH4¦f<
```